# OCR JPEG file to text

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to convert the attached OCR JPEG file to text. When I use pytesseract or tesseract, I am seeing diacritics because of which my output contains a lot of junk characters. Also, conversion of jpeg to text is not working.

I tried to read from the image file, extract text, and print using keystrokes. The output is not as expected.

The code is as follows:

```
image=Image.open('8001.jpg')
text = image_to_string(image, lang='eng')
keyboard.write(text)
```

I am getting some unwanted characters like these:

> >) ) 7? ) 7 0
> Daybreak: appeared. Ihe mowing miosls ourvounded us, bub Urey 2001 cleared ch J Wea
>
> > pm 0. 0 ) ) aeaboul lo examine the hull, which formed on deely a kind of horizontal
> 2
>
> fatfoun, w fen a J felt ils
> op
> nel, kicking the resounding plate. “Open,
>
> ) me " 57
> gradually sinking. Oh! confound i! cried Nod
>
> 0 Q yi
> you inhoapitable zasealy!
>
> Says Pp iy ui
>
> 0 0
> cide, came from the interior of the Boal. One iton plate was moved, a men appeared, ullered

Comment: Link to my file https://www.plustransfer.com/download.php?id=2671aa1153f0402615141fd7f2f1011a

Comment: Is your only option JPEG file ?
JPEG is probably the worst format for text if the image resolution is small.

If you can, try to get a image that has less compression and a larger resolution.

Comment: Yes. As you mentioned, the only available option is JPEG. I don't have any other option. Can i try converting the same image to png or any other rich format? Is it possible?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/knwzu0wupkahff1/8001.jpg?dl=0
This is the actual file and this is the picture quality. Any way possible to extract the data ?

Comment: Eswar. No. converting JPG to something else is still going to give you the artifacts that are in jpeg files

Comment: Hello Oddmar Dam. Oh!!!. I don't have any other format then. This is the only available format.

Comment: Can you get it in a better resolution then ?

Comment: I requested, but this the only available file

Comment: Did you follow this example ?
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/

Comment: I tried the same. But no luck. It is able to find only a very limited pattern in that file and not full file.

Comment: I would say you need some deep learning with a lot of training.

The problem with they image, is that it's a very difficult font to OCR and the jpg quality is to low.